# can't run 2 runnable action in same ActionSequence

Tags: libgdx, runnable

I was trying to run 2 Runnable action in the same action sequence, but I get an error, saying that it `cannot resolve constructor SuquenceAction`.. Not sure if I missed something entirely obvious and merely having bad sight, but it appears that one can not run 2 Runnable action in sequence. What is the workaround? My sincere apologies if I am missing a syntax error here.

error:

**`no suitable constructor found for SequenceAction(ColorAction,RunnableAction,ColorAction,ColorAction,ColorAction,RunnableAction,ColorAction)`**

```
ColorAction colorToBlack= new ColorAction();
                    colorToBlack.setDuration(0.2f);
                    colorToBlack.setEndColor(Color.BLACK);
                    colorToBlack.setTime(0.2f);

                    ColorAction colorToWhite = new ColorAction();
                    colorToWhite.setDuration(0.2f);
                    colorToWhite.setEndColor(Color.WHITE);
                    colorToWhite.setTime(0.2f);

                    ColorAction wait = new ColorAction();
                    wait.setDuration(2.5f);
                    wait.setTime(2.5f);

                    ColorAction colorToBlack2= new ColorAction();
                    colorToBlack2.setDuration(0.2f);
                    colorToBlack2.setEndColor(Color.BLACK);
                    colorToBlack2.setTime(0.2f);

                    ColorAction colorToWhite2 = new ColorAction();
                    colorToWhite2.setDuration(0.2f);
                    colorToWhite2.setEndColor(Color.WHITE);
                    colorToWhite2.setTime(0.2f);

                SequenceAction sq = new SequenceAction(colorToBlack,Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                }),colorToWhite,wait,colorToBlack2,Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                }),colorToWhite2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, No constructor found. It is because there is no constructor in `SequenceAction` class which can take 7 Actions. The maximum is 5.

Here is the JavaDoc for [SequenceAction](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/SequenceAction.html)

The solution for this is, create `SequenceAction` object and add Actions 1 by 1 in order.

```
SequenceAction sq = new SequenceAction();

sq.addAction(colorToBlack);
sq.addAction(Actions.run(() -> {/**Using lambda expression, it's similar to New Runnable() { run() } **/} ));
sq.addAction(colorToWhite);
sq.addAction(wait);
sq.addAction(colorToBlack2);
sq.addAction(Actions.run(() -> {}));
sq.addAction(colorToWhite2);
```

As if you look into LibGdx code, in the constructor what they are doing is

```
public SequenceAction (Action action1, Action action2, Action action3, Action action4, Action action5) {
        addAction(action1);
        addAction(action2);
        addAction(action3);
        addAction(action4);
        addAction(action5);
}
```

It is similar to what I gave you.

I hope it helped :)

Comment: Thank you! Did not think of that.

Comment: Oh and is it safe to use lambda expressions? Not sure how libgdx handles newer Java functionality..

Comment: Don't worry about that, it's Java 8 feature. I use Lambda everywhere. What you are doing is just passing in a Runnable Object created using Lambda Style.

Comment: There is a tutorial/sample of a working RunnableAction on LibGDX.info, check it out here: https://libgdx.info/runnable-action/